# Is this variable resistor not connected to ground?

Tags: potentiometer, 555

I want to build the following PWM fan controller circuit:

[image: PWM Fan Controller]

I am not sure about the connection of potentiometer. Usually one of the terminals is connected to the supply voltage and the other is connected to ground. Here it seems one of the terminals is connected to the VCC but the other terminal is floating. Will it work without ground connection? Can someone explain this part of the circuit please?

Comment: I see only one potentiometer and all three of its terminals are terminated. No terminals are floating. If you look at the image in full resolution you will see that the wiper is connected to THR and TRI. R. Girish needs to get a better schematic editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potentiometer may be used anywhere in a circuit where you want a variable resistance.  Occasionally, one end of the resistance element will be connected to Vcc, and the other end connected to Ground, with an output taken from the wiper (moving contact), as you apparently expect.  However, they are often used in other situations where neither end of the resistance is connected to Vcc or Ground.

In your circuit, the ends of the resistance element are connected to D1 cathode and D2 anode, with the wiper connected to the top of C1.  In this circuit, I believe this allows the pot to adjust the duty cycle of the 555 PWM output.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This was the first time I saw a pot used like this. Yes the pot is there to adjust the PWM output.

Comment: Just to clarify. The diodes and the arrangement of the pot are intended for obtaining a variable duty cycle using a single 555 timer. The PWM signal can go from approximately 5% to 99% +/- components tolerance.